# Retrieving integer data from JSON and displaying on separate activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am converting JSON data from a server to String and storing in an ArrayList so that I can display the data on a separate activity page. With my string values, this is working perfectly fine. However, when I try with my integer values, my app crashes with a fatal error.

This is my loop to convert the JSON data to strings and add to Array.

```
for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    String make = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("make").toString();
    String model = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("model").toString();
    String reg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("license_number").toString();
    int year = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString());
    int price = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("price").toString());
    String colour = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("colour").toString();
    int number_doors = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("number_doors").toString());
    String transmission = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("transmission").toString();
    int mileage = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("mileage").toString());
    String fuel_type = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("fuel_type").toString();
    int engine_size = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("engine_size").toString());
    String body_style = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("body_style").toString();
    String condition = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("condition").toString();
    String notes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("notes").toString();

    Vehicle V = new Vehicle(make,model, year, price, reg, colour, number_doors, transmission, mileage, fuel_type,engine_size, body_style, condition, notes);
    vehicleArrayList.add(V);
}
```

I then have an on click listener so when an object is selected it will take you to another activity with fully populated details on each vehicle.

```
vehicleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("license_number", vehicleArrayList.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

And this is the code in my DetailsActivity.class that clicking on an object should take you to.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) extras.get("license_number");
System.out.println("received from the intent: " + vehicle.getLicense_number());

    TextView reg = findViewById(R.id.vecReg);
    TextView make = findViewById(R.id.make);
    TextView model = findViewById(R.id.model);
//    TextView year = findViewById(R.id.year);
//    TextView price = findViewById(R.id.price2);
    TextView colour = findViewById(R.id.colour2);
    TextView transmission = findViewById(R.id.transmission2);
//    TextView mileage = findViewById(R.id.mileage2);
    TextView fuel = findViewById(R.id.fuel2);
//    TextView engine = findViewById(R.id.engine2);
//    TextView doors = findViewById(R.id.doors2);
    TextView body = findViewById(R.id.body2);
    TextView condition = findViewById(R.id.condition2);
    TextView notes = findViewById(R.id.notes2);


    reg.setText(vehicle.getLicense_number());
    make.setText(vehicle.getMake());
    model.setText(vehicle.getModel());
//    year.setText(vehicle.getYear());
//    price.setText(vehicle.getPrice());
    colour.setText(vehicle.getColour());
    transmission.setText(vehicle.getTransmission());
//    mileage.setText(vehicle.getMileage());
    fuel.setText(vehicle.getFuel_type());
//    engine.setText(vehicle.getEngine_size());
//    doors.setText(vehicle.getNumber_doors());
    body.setText(vehicle.getBody_style());
    condition.setText(vehicle.getCondition());
    notes.setText(vehicle.getNotes());
```

As you can see, I have commented out the integer values as whenever I have not commented them out, I receive the fatal error. This is from my logcat.

```
03-28 12:40:56.959 16172-16172/com.example.vehicledatabaseapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vehicledatabaseapp, PID: 16172
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vehicledatabaseapp/com.example.vehicledatabaseapp.DetailsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7df
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7df
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
        at com.example.vehicledatabaseapp.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
03-28 12:40:59.856 16172-16172/com.example.vehicledatabaseapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16172 SIG: 9
```

The line `"com.example.vehicledatabaseapp.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:42)"` is referring to the line `"year.setText(vehicle.getYear());"`

Comment: check the id for your year textview in xml layout file

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert your `int` value to `String` before set it to `TextView`.

```
year.setText(String.valueOf(vehicle.getYear()))
```